# Unable to run Spring in Docker - Apple M1

Tags: spring, docker, logback, apple-m1

Recently I switched from *Intel* chip Mac to *M1* one, and im unable to run few of a services using **Docker**. All the services are defined in **docker-compose file** and when I start it all the *Spring* services have the same issue.

It is my Logback config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration scan="true">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <springProfile name="!dev">
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/inp_server_logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <encoder>
                <charset>utf-8</charset>
                <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</Pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </springProfile>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>512</queueSize>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="javax.activation" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.mail" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.management.remote" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="javax.xml.bind" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="ch.qos.logback" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.netflix" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.netflix.discovery" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="com.ryantenney" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.sun" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.undertow" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="io.undertow.websockets.jsr" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="OFF"/>
    <logger name="org.bson" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.validator" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="pl.inpeak" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.reflections" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.cache" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.thymeleaf" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.xnio" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="springfox.documentation.schema.property" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="sun.rmi.transport" level="WARN"/>

    <!-- https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHook and https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1090 -->
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

</configuration>
```

And that's the error output from console:

```
server_1         | Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
server_1         | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:87 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:87 - no applicable action for [rollingPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:34 - no applicable action for [fileNamePattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][fileNamePattern]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:29 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][maxHistory]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:22 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:26 - no applicable action for [charset], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][charset]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@15:26 - no applicable action for [Pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][Pattern]]
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
server_1         |  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
server_1         |  at pl.inpeak.InpeakServerApp$Companion.main(InpeakServerApp.kt:77)
server_1         |  at pl.inpeak.InpeakServerApp.main(InpeakServerApp.kt)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
server_1         | 2021-08-09 12:27:20.904 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
server_1         | 
server_1         | java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:87 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:87 - no applicable action for [rollingPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:34 - no applicable action for [fileNamePattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][fileNamePattern]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:29 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][maxHistory]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:22 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:26 - no applicable action for [charset], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][charset]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@15:26 - no applicable action for [Pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][Pattern]]
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:328)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
server_1         |  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
server_1         |  at pl.inpeak.InpeakServerApp$Companion.main(InpeakServerApp.kt:77)
server_1         |  at pl.inpeak.InpeakServerApp.main(InpeakServerApp.kt)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
server_1         | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:87 - no applicable action for [appender], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:87 - no applicable action for [rollingPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:34 - no applicable action for [fileNamePattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][fileNamePattern]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:29 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][rollingPolicy][maxHistory]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:22 - no applicable action for [encoder], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:26 - no applicable action for [charset], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][charset]]
server_1         | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@15:26 - no applicable action for [Pattern], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][springProfile][appender][encoder][Pattern]]
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
server_1         |  at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
server_1         |  ... 22 common frames omitted
server_1         | 
server_1 exited with code 0
```

Everything works fine on every setup but this Apple M1 chip one. Could this logback configuration be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running docker desktop for Mac, have you checked: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/ ? You need to download the preview for docker to work on M1.

Comment: It's not a preview anymore, as that page you linked to says: Docker Desktop for Mac on Apple silicon is now available as a GA release (GA means: "general availability", it's not a preview release).

Comment: I've got this version already installed, as Jesper mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try running native in ARM64 building a arm64 docker image.

See a similar issue that I answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68992222/7870598

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check whether the base image is compatible with the linux/arm64.

I would suggest to run the container with `--platform=linux/amd64`and check the output.
Else try to build the docker container by passing `--platform=linux/arm64`

Ex:- `FROM --platform=linux/arm64 <base_image>`