# Docker image runs on Intel mac but not M1 mac

Tags: java, docker, jvm, alpine-linux, apple-m1

We have a Java Spring Boot application that runs in a Docker container.  It is based on openjdk:13-jdk-alpine.  We deploy it to Linux machines, but we are also able to run it locally on Windows machines, as well as on an Intel-based iMac.

We have found, though, that it cannot run properly on an ARM-based MacBook Pro.  The exceptions we get are basic Java errors like "Can't find symbol Java.class[]," and other things that look like the JVM is off.

Is there a way to build a Docker image that will work on all these platforms, including the M1 MacBook Pro?

Comment: If [this](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/13-jdk-alpine/images/sha256-26ca1df9692d34f30ed38d272fb7b1776b832464b099d6d29f416787be4af170?context=explore) is your base image, then you are out of luck. The image is only available for amd64 architecture, not for ARM.

Comment: Why do you deploy with a jdk and not jre, though? It increases your size for no reason at all

Comment: @Eugene That's a great point, and we will address that.  But it wouldn't have any impact on the issue, I assume.

Comment: @Turing85 Is there a JRE/Linux image that would work for both architectures?  I just ran into an article about multi-arch images.  Would that do the trick?

Comment: Right, my point is that you could most probably deploy with any jre up to 15, cause in the 16 when module system started deprecated things and this might break things for your application.

Comment: couldnt find any arm based openjdk image tagged as 13-jdk-* or 13-jre-*, if @Eugene is correct maybe use a newer image, though you could anyway use this image https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk13/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Answer (score 7):

I made it work with the following image.
I pulled the image with

```
docker pull bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine-musl:17
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine-musl:17
ADD build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Now the `docker build` command worked

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: not for me:
17: Pulling from bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine-musl
no matching manifest for darwin/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of problems with Java containers too on my M1 macbook. For your problem, maybe you need to create your own docker image:

Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt update \
    && apt upgrade -y \
    && apt install -y openjdk-13-jre git \
    && apt clean

RUN mkdir -pv /app && cd /app && \
    git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git && \
    cd /app/gs-spring-boot/initial && ./gradlew build

WORKDIR /app/gs-spring-boot/initial

ENTRYPOINT [ "./gradlew", "bootRun" ]
```

Build image

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run container

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 test
```

Go to http://localhost:8080/ on your browser and your Spring-Boot application is running without Rosetta 2.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Java developer and my Dockerfile is for Proof of Concept purpose.

Remember that your Docker image is builded to ARM64 architecture. If you wanna run this container on a Intel/AMD processor, you have to change `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04` on your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Build your images with [multiarch](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/) support to get rid of all possible architecture failures in the future. To do this cleanly, avoid using anything related to the platform in your Dockerfile, just old-school Dockerfiles are ok.

If you are using github and github-actions, you may check [this](https://github.com/raxetul/alpine-s6-nginx-php/blob/master/.github/workflows/docker-publish.yml) to build your images and push them into your image repository. This can be also used for building images which work on RaspberryPi like SBCs.

Answer (score 0):

it's because image is not supported for m1 yet, you can build it for cross platform and run it

```
docker build --platform=linux/arm64 -t image:latest .
```

Answer (score 0):

remplace the image you have with this

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim-buster
```